# Google apps script using UrlFetchApp.fetch getting an error when making request with XML data

Tags: google-apps-script

EDIT: Regarding Jonathon's comment:

When running this code I get the following error:

Invalid argument: http://production.shippingapis.com/ShippingAPI.dll?API=Verify&XML=6406%20Ivy%20LaneGreenbeltMD

Here is the code in question.  I did not include my USER ID:

```
function validate_address() {

  //var userID = 'xxxxxxxxxxx';
  //var address1 = '204 main street apt 4';
  //var address2 = '';
  //var city = '';
  //var state = '';
  //var zip5 = '12601';
  //var zip4 = '';

  //Will switch out hard coded values with variables once I get it working.

  var XMLhttp_request = 'http://production.shippingapis.com/ShippingAPI.dll?API=Verify&XML=<AddressValidateRequest USERID="xxxxxxxxxxx"><Address><Address1></Address1><Address2>6406 Ivy Lane</Address2><City>Greenbelt</City><State>MD</State><Zip5></Zip5><Zip4></Zip4></Address></AddressValidateRequest>';

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(XMLhttp_request, options);

  Logger.log(response.getContentText());

}
```

USPS address validation API has some example code on their website.  When I use the code with my USER ID, copy and paste it straight into the URL bar it works and I get the XML i'm looking for.

Comment: I've upvoted your answer, but this question could yet be improved by including what the actual error was that you were looking to fix.

Comment: I have reproduced the error on my end and copied it into the post.  Thanks for the feedback, new to stack overflow =)

Answer (score 1):

So I figured this out for myself.  Here is the documentation that helped me:
[Google apps scripts documentation Parsing XML](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/external)

The mistake in my previous code was combining the URL to the api and the arguments together.  You can see below they are now separated, with the query as an object passed in as the options argument.  One thing to note is the "?" symbol before the query is not at the beginning of my payload variable.  Although it was included in the USPS documentation when you paste it straight into an address bar, in G.A.S you leave it out.

And here is the code that worked for me.  Hope this helps someone else.

```
function validate_address() {

  //var userID = 'xxxxxxxxxxx';
  //var address1 = '204 main street apt 4';
  //var address2 = '';
  //var city = '';
  //var state = '';
  //var zip5 = '12601';
  //var zip4 = '';

  //Will switch out hard coded values with variables once I get it working.

  var payload = 'API=Verify&XML=<AddressValidateRequest USERID="xxxxxxxxxxxx"><Address><Address1></Address1><Address2>6406 Ivy Lane</Address2><City>Greenbelt</City><State>MD</State><Zip5></Zip5><Zip4></Zip4></Address></AddressValidateRequest>';

  var url = 'http://production.shippingapis.com/ShippingAPI.dll';

  var options = {
    'method': 'get',
    'headers': {
        "Accept": "application/xml"
    },
    'payload': payload
};

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);

  Logger.log(response.getContentText());

  //Logger.log(XMLhttp_request);
}
```